"GET PROCESSING OPTIONS failed" error while reading a smart card with cardpeek software
I'm currently having a problem while reading a card with cardpeek software.
At the starts and end of the operation i keep on getting this error:
GET PROCESSING OPTIONS failed, the script will continue to read the card
Does anyone what this is caused by and how it can be fixed?
I didn't really know what to change because i am not experienced, but i expected it to just run without a htich.

Please fix the question as it does not contain anything the is needed to create an answer. You might want to provide logs, for instance.
